# Finding all analytic functions whose real part consists of an unknown function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I've managed to solve a dozen problems like these before, but I'm stuck at those including an unknown function such as the one below.

> Determine all analytic functions $f(z)=u+iv$ with the real part of the form $u(x,y)=\varphi(x)(1-y)$ where $u(x,y)\in\mathcal{C}^2$ and which moreover satisfy $f(0)=0$. The answer should be expressed as a function of the variable $z=x+iy$.

What I've tried this far is of course to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. They give us
$$
v_x=-u_y=\varphi(x) \\
v_y=u_x=\varphi'(x)(1-y)=\varphi'(x)-y\varphi'(x).
$$
Thus
$$
v(x,y)=\int\varphi(x)dx+\Psi(y) \\
v(x,y)=y\varphi'(x)-\frac{y^2}{2}\varphi'(x)+\Phi(x).
$$
This is where I get stuck. What I see is a crazy mixture of derivatives and integrals. The final result is $f(z)=a\left(z+\frac{iz^2}{2}\right)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, which obviously doens't contain $\varphi(x)$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u(x,y)$ is a harmonic function, which means $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$.  Since $u_{yy} = 0$, this part is easy to solve (obtaining $u$ depending on two parameters, of which one is eliminated by the $f(0)=0$).  Then use Cauchy-Riemann to get $v$.

Comment: I don't see why $u(x,y)$ is harmonic. Is this a direct result of $u(x,y)\in C^2$? If so: Why? I don't really follow on the remaining part. I assume that a more explicit answer would help. Once I see how to change my train of thought everything else will fall into place on its own.

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of an analytic function are harmonic.  This follows from Cauchy-Riemann plus the fact they are $C^2$ (which actually doesn't have to be assumed separately, but presumably you haven't got to that fact in your course).

Comment: Okay. Obviously $u_{yy}=0$. Thus $u_y=A$, $u=Ay+B$, but $u(0,0)=B=0$. Hence $v_x=-u_y=-A$ and $v=-Ax+\Psi(y)$. Moreover $u_{xx}=0$ since $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=u_{xx}=0$. Hence $u_x=A$, $u=Ax+B$, but $u(0,0)=B=0$. Thus $v_y=u_x=A$ and $v=Ay+\Phi(x)$. Furthermore $v=-Ax+\Psi(y)=Ay+\Phi(x)\Rightarrow v=-Ax+Ay$ and $u=Ax+Ay$. Thus $f(z)=Ax+Ay+i(-Ax+Ay)$. Now I never used $u(x,y)=\varphi(x)(1-y)$, and the key tells me otherwise. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not constants.  $u(x,y) = \phi(x)(1-y)$ so $u_{xx} = 0 = \phi''(x)(1-y)$.

Comment: Okay. I'm still stuck with this. Now I have $u_{xx}=0\Rightarrow u=\varphi(x)(1-y)$ and $u_{yy}=0\Rightarrow u\varphi(x)y+\varphi(x)$, but evaluating $u(0,0)=0$ yields $\varphi(0)=0$. I think a more elaborate answer would be adequate.

Comment: If $u = \varphi(x)(1-y)$, $u_{xx} = \varphi''(x)(1-y)$.  For that to be $0$ (for all $x$ and $y$), $\varphi''(x) = 0$.  Now can you solve that?

Comment: Obviously I'm missing something obvious. It's starting to become a little embarrassing. For $u_{xx}=\varphi''(x)(1-y)=0$ for all $x$ and $y$ one of course needs either $1-y=0$ or $\varphi''(x)=0$, but $1-y=0\Leftrightarrow y=1$ and $\varphi''(x)=0\Rightarrow\varphi(x)=Ax+B$ for some $A$ and $B$. Hence we need said $\varphi(x)$ for $u_{xx}=\varphi''(x)(1-y)=0$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: OK, now you have $\varphi(x) = Ax + B$, so $u(x,y) = (Ax+B)(1-y)$.  And from $u(0,0) = 0$ you get $B = 0$.  Now use Cauchy-Riemann to find $v(x,y)$.